# query for daily count in django

Tags: python, django

I have a log model as 
**models.py**

```
class Log(models.Model):
    module         = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,default=None,  max_length=20)
    mobile         = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,max_length=15)
    incoming_text  = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,)
    outgoing_text  = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False,)
    shortcode      = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=6)
    network        = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=15)
    user           = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=15)
    created_on     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False, blank=False)
    campaign      = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=30)
```

now I have to generate the query in django such that the total daily count on the basis of created_on field is reqquired. how can I acheive it in django?

Answer (score 0):

`Log.objects.filter(pub_date=datetime.date.today()).count()` . This should work